# Play eclipse debugger - Remote scala application

Tags: scala

How can I debug a Play(2.1)/Scala app using eclipse ?
I have run play server using "play debug run" in a prompt. I am getting the "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999" message but now I am trying to launch my app in debug mode through eclipse. I have read that in Java this can be done by clicking on "Remote Java Application" but how to do it for a Scala app ? There are no Remote Scala application item.

Comment: Scala runs on the JVM, so look for a remote Java application

Comment: When runing a remote Java application I get the error "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.".